# Deadline for the Spring 14' DEV 401 exam and find what's changed in this release

Tags: spring14, dev401

I'm planning to do my DEV 401 for the first time as soon as possible and I need to know the deadline for the Spring 14'. Also i'm bit stuck finding the updates for this release. It'll be a great help to know what should be covered, any resources for the spring 14' before taking the exam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Spring '14 maintenance deadline is October 31, 2014 - if that is what you mean?

You can always find the deadlines on the [certification website here](http://certification.salesforce.com/schedules).

Salesforce recommend at the very least for this exam you watch the training videos on force.com, analytics and mobile [which you can find here](http://www.salesforce.com/customer-resources/releases/spring14/release-training.jsp).

Don't forget you get three attempts at the maintenance exams, and it will ask a mixture of new feature material (from the videos) and standard platform questions to make sure you are properly in the loop.

If you just mean you are planning on taking the force.com certified developer exam, you will have missed the opportunity to take it as a Spring'14 developer (Exam code SP14) and you will have to accept that it's possible for you now to get questions for Summer'14 (SU14). To be honest, the scale of that difference will not be massive, you are pretty much either able to pass the certified exam or not! Watching the release material for Summer'14 would be useful if you are heading into that exam though. That is also on the training website linked about (just poison the URL to summer14)

I have given a presentation at Developer User Groups on the topic of getting certified, which you can find on my blog here:

http://srlawr.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/getting-your-certified-forcecom.html

Your core resource (As mentioned in my comment) for the certification exam is the [fundamentals book](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/index.htm) though

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have not done the exam before, i'm going to take it for the first time (Not maintenance exams, the actual very first exam with 60 mcq questions). So i'm bit confused if I take the exam by the end of October what exam i'll be taking (Spring 14 or Summer 14 or what), so what material I should be looking to ?

Comment: Taking the exam now will mean you get the Summer 14 exam. You can tell which one it is from the certification registration site, the code after the title references the release (i.e. it currently says SU14 for summer'14). The actual current release is NOT the biggest factor in the exam by a long shot though, the majority of the 60 questions are on the core of the force.com platform, so the fundamentals book, apex workbooks etc. are much more useful and relevant than release specific training material.